# Custom EditText default cursor position

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view

I have a custom EditText. It has a non editable prefix and suffix, and an editable middle part. The issue is **default cursor position is always at the starting of editable text**, as seen in screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

This is the `onDraw()` of my custom view.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    suffixXPosition = (int) (textPaint.measureText(getText().toString()) + leftPadding + textPaint.measureText(prefix));
    canvas.drawText(prefix, prefixXPosition, getBaseline(), textPaint);
    canvas.drawText(getText().toString(), stringXPosition, getBaseline(), textPaint);
    canvas.drawText(suffix, suffixXPosition, getBaseline(), textPaint);
}
```

It's pretty basic. It just draws the text on canvas.

**I want the cursor to appear at the end of editable text when EditText is rendered**
How can I do that? **I want the view to handle this situation itself.**

I tried `setSelection(getText().toString().length());` in onDraw method. It draws the cursor in the right position. But that makes me unable to change cursor position on touch event.

Comment: Don't set the cursor position in onDraw.  Set a focus listener and set it when you gain focus.

Comment: @GabeSechan It allows me to change cursor position unlike in the onDraw approach. But when the view is first rendered, cursor is still in the wrong position.

Comment: Then call it at creation time as well

Comment: @GabeSechan Creation time? you mean when the constructor is called? I believe onDraw will be called after that and draw cursor in the wrong position.

Comment: Why would it draw it in the wrong position? It will draw it where you set it. It shouldn't set the position in on draw at all

Comment: @GabeSechan I am not talking about setting position in onDraw. I tried setting selection position in constructor. but when `super.onDraw()` is called while drawing the view, it resets cursor to the wrong position.

Comment: Super.on draw is not setting the cursor position. Something else may be, but it isn't on draw

Comment: @GabeSechan I tried without `super.onDraw` and it is not drawing the cursor at all. That's why I assumed `super.onDraw` is responsible for this issue. I think I need some function that is called after `onDraw` and set selection in there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the cursor position in [**onAttachedToWindow()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onAttachedToWindow())

> This is called when the view is attached to a window. At this point it has a Surface and will start drawing. Note that this function is guaranteed to be called before onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas), however it may be called any time before the first onDraw -- including before or after onMeasure(int, int).

```
@Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() { 
        super.onAttachedToWindow(); 
        setSelection(getText().toString().length());//set your cursor position
    }
```